# How to transform value of type Date obtained asynchronously from .ts file in Angular into moment() function?

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm curious how to customize the value obtained by using 'subscribe' in Angular's ts file and display it in an html file.

The NewsService was injected from the home.component.ts file, and the value was received from the server and stored in a variable called 'News'.

Rows corresponding to the attributes of 'id,title, description,date, is_visible' are stored in the 'News' variable, and it is displayed as n.title, n.date... in the html file.

The problem is that if you show date through {{n.date}}, ISO-8601 date format is displayed as shown in the picture. Like 2021-08-21T15:00:00.000Z.

I want to show only 2021-08-21 in 2021-08-21T15:00:00.000Z output value. Is there any way to do it through moment() function??

I would like to know how to parse only the desired part through the moment function in the ts file or parse it directly from the html file.

---

home.component.ts / NewsService/ html file/ News database/ Output result/ is attached below. thank you!

```
//home.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { INews } from 'src/app/shared/models/news';
import { NewsService } from 'src/app/shared/services/news.service';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private ns: NewsService) { }

  News : INews[]=[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ns.getAll().subscribe(News => {
       this.News = News.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    });
  }

}
```

```
//news.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { IResponse } from '../models/response';
import { INews } from '../models/news';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<INews[]> {
    return this.http.get<IResponse>(`${environment.apiUrl}/events/r/all`)
      .pipe( map(res => res.data) );
  }

}
```

```
//part of home.component.html

<table class="news-table">
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Views</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor = "let n of News">
              <td><a>{{n.title}}</a></td>
              <td>진행 중</td>
              <td>{{n.date}}</td>
              <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            
          </table>
```

```
//news database (datagrip screenshot)
//output result


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd1MY.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOMaB.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnfzd.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

no yow bro, moment is to heavy and to old to be use, it is not worth it with pure js all you need is a line of code

`new Date(dateFromBackEnd).toLocaleDateString()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date: Date | string = '2021-08-21T15:00:00.000Z';
var formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `moment` you can easily achieve the date format which you want! Please have a look

```
console.log(moment('2021-08-21T15:00:00.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

**OutPut**
[image]